# Text Parse - Need to extract text after (E) lengh 17 char

Tags: javascript, parsing, text, text-parsing

I need to extract the following text (KNAB3512BJT142015) but none of my formula works as my marker are brackets and mess with the formula

here the global text :

de la Collectivité,
Paralegatio
d
RE
(D.2.1) B3512
(E) **KNAB3512BJT142015**
(F.3) 2T070
(J.3) CI
(P.6) 7

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "de la Collectivité, Paralegatio d RE (D.2.1) B3512 (E) KNAB3512BJT142015 (F.3) 2T070 (J.3) CI (P.6) 7";
var from = "(E) "
var start = str.indexOf(from) + from.length;
var result = str.slice(start, start + 17);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape brackets

```js
const str = `de la Collectivité, Paralegatio d RE (D.2.1) B3512 (E) KNAB3512BJT142015 (F.3) 2T070 (J.3) CI (P.6) 7`

const re1 = /\(E\) (\w+) \(/; // grab until next space and left bracket
console.log(str.match(re1)[1])

const re2 = /\(E\) (\w{17}) \(/; // grab 17 chars after (E) pluse space
console.log(str.match(re2)[1])

console.log(str.split("(E)")[1].slice(1,18)); //split on (E) and take the next 17 after skipping the space
```